# Erc20 token with rewards

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, reward, shares

I want to create an etc 20 token that can be used to rais funds for projects and later distributes the revenue from the project to people who bought the token. How to do that ?

Comment: By writing code.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad.

An ERC20 token gives you the accounting and transferability as well as compatibility with wallets and exchanges.

Great.

In theory, you can sell the tokens for money if anyone will buy them. Why would they? It's not a rhetorical question.

This is an economics, mechanism-design question. It's a little too broad to describe exactly how to define the entitlements or value the buyer would receive by way of possessing your token. Generally, buyers need to get something besides a token that is worthless, by default.

It is your task to define that value and then produce code that links it to the token.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am planing to rais funds via erc 20 token and reward the owners in DAI coin. I want to use the funds for renewable energy projects. The electricity generated will be sold to government for fiat currency that would be converted to DAI and distributed as reward.     How do i keep track of addresses that hold my erc 20 token to distribute reward ?           Basically i want to convert a Corporate bond into a smart contract.

Comment: Keeping track of who owns them is what an ERC20 contract does.